# What's the meaning of 'R' in the type name 'PRKMUTEX' in wdm.h?

Tags: c, windows

A short example excerpted from wdm.h

```
typedef struct _KMUTANT {
    DISPATCHER_HEADER Header;
    LIST_ENTRY MutantListEntry;
    struct _KTHREAD *OwnerThread;
    BOOLEAN Abandoned;
    UCHAR ApcDisable;
} KMUTANT, *PKMUTANT, *PRKMUTANT, KMUTEX, *PKMUTEX, *PRKMUTEX;
```

I know 'P' means 'Pointer', but I don't know what 'R' means.

Any interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `R` identifies the pointer as a [restricted pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict).

Comment: Please remember to accept if this was the information you were looking for.

Comment: Sounds reasoble. But what is the use of having 2X2 different names for the same type?

Comment: @alk MSFT in their great wisdom doesn't support `restrict`. More generally ... google "typedef".

Answer (score -1):

**obviously**, "R == restricted pointer"